# How to print NULL when table has no rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with a named column but no rows.

```
Col1
```

I wanted to write a select similar to:

```
SELECT TOP(1)
    NULLIF(Col1, '')
FROM table
```

I wanted to get a result like:

```
   Col1
1  NULL
```

But instead I get just the `Col1` name and no results. How can I get a table with `NULL` as the result?

Comment: FYI, a `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` will return arbitrary rows. They could easily be different every time you run the query. Are you saying you want a *random* value in the column `Col1` from your table `table`?

Comment: Your question is vague because it doesn't specify what to do if there are rows.

Comment: The specific assumption is that the table is empty. In this case, I have something different to handle if there are rows. This is more of a general question for empty tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```sql
    select max(col1)
    from t;
```

An aggregation query with no `group by` or `having` always returns one row.  If there are no rows then the value is (generally) `NULL` for aggregation functions (the exception is `COUNT()`).